# Randomly select x number of elements from a list

Tags: python, list, random, selection

I am trying to write a code that will randomly select between 1 and 4 elements of a list 50 times. The list I am working with is `['nu', 'ne', 'na', 'ku', 'ke', 'ka']`.

So essentially, I want it to output something like

```
nukuna
ke
keka
nuka
nane
nanenu
nu
nukekanu
kunu
...
```

50 times

Comment: What script / programming languages do you use?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: How about repetition: kukukuku would be allowed?

Comment: repetition is allowed

Answer (score 0):

**In Python:**

```
import random

input  = [...] # Your input strings
output = ''

random.seed() # Seed the random generator

for i in range(0,len(input)):
    N = 1+random.randrange(4) # Choose a random number between 1 and 4
    for j in range(0,N): # Choose N random items out of the input
        index = random.randrange(len(input)-j)
        temp = input[index]
        input[index] = input[len(input)-j-1]
        input[len(input)-j-1] = temp
        output += temp
    output += ' '

print output
```

**In C:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

char* input[NUM_OF_INPUT_STRINGS] = {...}; // Your input strings
char output[MAX_SIZE_OF_OUTPUT+1];

// Seed the random generator
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

for (int i=0; i<NUM_OF_INPUT_STRINGS; i++)
{
    // Set the output string empty
    output[0] = 0;
    // Choose a random number between 1 and 4
    int N = 1+(rand()%4);
    // Choose N random items out of the input
    for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
        int index = rand()%(NUM_OF_INPUT_STRINGS-j);
        char* temp = input[index];
        input[index] = input[NUM_OF_INPUT_STRINGS-j-1];
        input[NUM_OF_INPUT_STRINGS-j-1] = temp;
        strcat(output,temp);
    }
    // Print the output
    printf("%s ",output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the error of "list index out of range" in Python. How can I fix that?

Comment: Works fine for me; have you verified that the `input` array contains `NUM_OF_INPUT_STRINGS` strings?

Comment: Better yet - I replaced `NUM_OF_INPUT_STRINGS` with `len(input)`, so you can just put any number of strings in the `input` array...

Comment: Applied a small fix in the Python code, to avoid repeating the same character more than once...

Comment: this `for i in range(0,len(input)):` should be replaced with `for i in range(0,len(input)-1):`

Comment: @LiamGiannini: Your edit just caused someone to down-vote my answer (or was it you by any chance?)!!! In any case, I don't see why `len(input)` has to be replaced with `len(input)-1`. If you can explain it, then please do. Otherwise, please refrain from changing my answer, which I have already tested successfully.

Comment: @barakmanos it won't work, it will display the "list index out of range" error.

Comment: @LiamGiannini: The code (Python 2.7) prints `kenu kakena kuka ka nuke nekuke`. Please check your claims before posting them! Also, please revoke your unnecessary down-vote!!!!!

Comment: This code is very unpythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Python code:

```
import random

my_list = ['nu', 'ne', 'na', 'ku', 'ke', 'ka']

for i in xrange(0,50):
    tmp_string = ''
    count = random.randrange(1,4)      # choose a random between 1 and 4
    for j in xrange(0, count):
         # add a random member of the list to the temporary string
         tmp_string = tmp_string + random.choice(my_list)
    print tmp_string         # print each final string
```

Comment: I see that he has edited your post and down-voted it, just as he did with mine. This user should be banned from this website. I'm up-voting in order to "compensate" you for the damage.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, on top of what you've mentioned in a comment to his answer (the fact that he published an answer identical to a previous one here more than a year after it had been published), you might also want to check (and possibly revert) his edit to your own answer. In my case, not only did he down-vote the answer, but he also changed it from a working code to a non-working code.

Answer (score 0):

this is the easiest way to do it in python

```
from random import randint, choice

input_list = ['nu', 'ne', 'na', 'ku', 'ke', 'ka']


for x in range(50): (print "".join([choice(input_list) for x in range(randint(1,4))]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int i=0;
StringBuffer stb=new StringBuffer();
String[] arr= {"nu", "ne", "na", "ku", "ke", "ka"};
while(i<50){
int idx = new Random().nextInt(arr.length);
 stb.append(arr[idx]);

i++;
}
```

Comment: This does not match the requirements. It just hands out 50 random elements, not 50 Strings of up to four random elements.

Comment: oh this is java code > because you have mentioned language later.