# Random Output from a list - Python

Tags: python

```
Stores = ["alpha","bravo","charlie","delta"]
KnownName = Stores.pop()
KnownName2 = Stores.pop()
KnownName3 = Stores.pop()
print KnownName+" "+Stores.pop() 
print KnownName2+" "+KnownName
print KnownName3+" "+KnownName2 
print KnownName3
```

Output:

```
delta alpha
charlie delta
bravo charlie
bravo
```

So if I have a list of m1,m2,m3...mn
I am trying to get random out such as this

```
m1
m2 m3
m4 m2
m5
m6 m7
m8 m9
m10 m8
m11 m10
```

If you look at the outputs, a maximum of two values in a line. Only the first value can repeat.

How can I improve my code?

```
foo = ['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5','m6','m7','m8']
foo.reverse()
while foo:
    try:
        if random.randrange(0,2) == 0:
            print foo.pop()
        else:
            Value2 = foo.pop()
            print Value2 + " " + foo.pop()
            if random.randrange(0,2) == 0:
                Value3 = foo.pop()
                print Value3 + " " + Value2
            else:
                foo.pop() + foo.pop()
    except:
        break
```

Comment: I have tried some variations from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192435/randomly-select-x-number-of-elements-from-a-list but isn't really coming out for me well.

Comment: Then just use random indices in the range instead of `pop()` method.

Comment: How do I get unique values then for the first value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this.

```
from random import randint

foo = ['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5','m6','m7','m8']
while foo:
    x = randint(0, len(foo) - 1)
    y = randint(0, len(foo) - 1)
    while x == y and len(foo) > 1:
        y = randint(0, len(foo) - 1)
    if randint(0, 1) == 0 or len(foo) <= 1:
        print foo[x]
    else:
        print foo[y], foo[x]
    foo = foo[:x] + foo[x+1:]
```